# Automatic upload of 10KB file to web service?

Tags: web-services, upload, file-upload

I am writing an application, similar to Seti@Home, that allows users to run processing on their home machine, and then upload the result to the central server.

However, the final result is maybe a 10K binary file. (Processing to achieve this output is several hours.)

What is the simplest reliable automatic method to upload this file to the central server? What do I need to do server-side to prevent blocking? Perhaps having the client send mail is simple and reliable? NB the client program is currently written in Python, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email is not a good solution; you will run into potential ISP blocking and other anti-spam mechanisms.

The easiest way is over HTTP via a simple webservice.  Have a listener at your server that accepts the uploaded files as part of a HTTP POST and then dump them wherever they need to be post-processed.

Comment: Is there open source code for this type of webservice?
How do I prevent the service from blocking (if there is more than one request)?